# Some docker containers don't start on system boot

Tags: postgresql, ubuntu, redis, docker

I'm using docker restart policies on my containers (--restart=always) running on Ubuntu 14.04.

Example containers:

`docker run -d --restart=always redis:2.8`
`docker run -d --restart=always postgres:9.4`

When I reboot the machine the postgres container starts automatically but the redis container does not.

Is this a problem with docker restart policies or am I missing something?

Edit:
If found this in the docker docs:

> As of Docker 1.2, restart policies are the built-in Docker mechanism
>   for restarting containers when they exit. If set, restart policies
>   will be used when the Docker daemon starts up, as typically happens
>   after a system boot. Restart policies will ensure that linked
>   containers are started in the correct order.

Docker logs of redis container after reboot (redis container did not start):

```
[1] 17 Apr 15:32:27.261 # User requested shutdown...
[1] 17 Apr 15:32:27.261 * Saving the final RDB snapshot before exiting.
[1] 17 Apr 15:32:27.406 * DB saved on disk
[1] 17 Apr 15:32:27.406 # Redis is now ready to exit, bye bye...
```

Comment: what does `docker events` shows ? I guess the `docker run` that fails logs some text ?

Comment: @user2915097 Can't really use `docker events` because the system is shutting down? I added docker logs of the redis container to the question.

Comment: @user2915097 I remove the redis container an started it again. Now it seem to be working..

Comment: check the docs http://docs.docker.com/reference/commandline/cli/#events `docker events` should definitely work, and is highly useful

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem recently with Docker 18.06.3-ce.

There is an [open issue on github](https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/26195). It is not yet resolved and marked as a Docker daemon bug.

Comment: A link to a solution is welcome, but please ensure your answer is useful without it: [add context around the link](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there, then quote the most relevant part of the page you're linking to in case the target page is unavailable. [Answers that are little more than a link may be deleted](//stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers).

Comment: Thank you for the comment, I've added some information.